# Accessing JS Private Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, object

I am working on trying to make an JS object and access to private methods. The problem I am running into when trying to return a function is the private methods cannot be accessed. Code Below.

```
var Item = (function() {

    var price = 0;
    var name = '';
    var description = '';
    var quantity = '';
    var attributes = {};

    var Item = function(data) {

    }

    function setPrice(variable) {
        this.price = variable;
    };

    function getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    };

    function setName(variable) {
        this.name = variable;
    };

    function getName() {
        return this.name;
    };

    function setDescription(variable) {
        this.description = variable;
    };

    function setQuantity(variable) {
        this.quanity = variable;
    };

    return function(data){

        setPrice : setPrice;
        getPrice : getPrice;
        setName : setName;
        setDescription : setDescription;
        setQuantity : setQuantity;

        return new Item(data);
    }

})();

item2 = Item();
    item2.setPrice('3');
alert(item2.getPrice());
```

With this setup, how can I access the private methods?

Comment: Why would you want to access private methods? They are private for a reason.

Comment: I am following a design pattern called the Revealing Module. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: That setup doesn't make very much sense. The function you're returning from the self-executing function has a bunch of labels and then evaluates the functions. Furthermore, adding `this.` to it (after having changed `:` to `=`) won't do anything useful either because you're returning an `Item` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that pattern will work for what you're trying to do. I think using a pattern like this one will keep your code smaller and more reusable. This way you also get rid of the `set` functions.

```
var Item = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({
        price: 0,
        name: '',
        description: '',
        quantity: '',
        attributes: {}
    }, options);

    // ...
    this.getPrice = function() {
        return opts.price;
    };

    // ...
};

var item = new Item({
    price: 100,
    name: 'onehundred',
    // ...
});

alert(item.getPrice());
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/JryAk/

Items changed:

- Check your `return` statement
- `Item` is a var, you were trying to instantiate a class object `item2`

Comment: That doesn't quite work, I need to make multiple different items.Thats what the reason for instantiation.