# Access data in javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I ran `console.log(object)`. This is what is shown in the console:

[image]

How can I access any of this information? For example the info in `$oel`

Comment: `object.$oel` ?

Comment: Edited: sorry, that was too mean...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing JS Private Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595285/accessing-js-private-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Like many languages, JavaScript syntax uses "dot notation" to access properties on objects:

```
object.$oel
```

Those properties may be primitive values:

```
console.log(object.$oel)
```

or perhaps objects with their own properties:

```
console.log(object.$oel.someProperty)
```

or perhaps functions:

```
object.$oel()
```

Regardless of the type, the syntax to reach it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can you standard dot notation to access object attributes, eg:

```
object.attr;
```

Regards.